# PHP: remove all before last slash

Tags: php

I need to remove all text from url before last slash `/`

```
$url = https://example.com/aaa/bbbb/ccc/ttt/img.jpg
```

The output must be `img.jpg`

Also note `/aaa/bbb/ccc/ttt` in not the same

- must use regular expresion
- must be php 7 compatible

Answer (score 5):

Simplest solution should be `$file = basename($url);`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php